# Pass Query Parameters to Loader via Webpack Require Context

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, commonjs

I am using webpack's [require.context](https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/#requirecontext) to require a directory of thumbnail images. Furthermore in my webpack config file I am implementing a [responsive-loader](https://github.com/herrstucki/responsive-loader) to build various resolutions of each image.

I would like to manually pass a query parameter to the responsive-loader to build only 128 and 256 width images when I require the thumbnail directory.

How can I pass a query parameter through webpack's `require.context` method?

Here is my code so far...

```
thumbnailContext.keys().forEach(thumbnailPath => {
    thumbnailContext(`${thumbnailPath}?sizes[]=128,sizes[]=256`)
})
```

That code returns this error.

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module './First Post/thumbnail.png?sizes[]=128,sizes[]=256'
    at webpackContextResolve (webpack:///./src/posts_sync_thumbnail\.(:8080/png%7Cjpeg%7Cjpg)?:12:11)
```

Comment: Was a solution ever found for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pass the parameters as part of the first argument of `require.context`.

Example:

```
require.context('my-loader?sizes[]=128,sizes[]=256!./img', true, /\.png$/i);
```

If you want to ignore all other loaders that might be configured, prefix it with !!

```
require.context('!!my-loader!./img', true, /\.png$/i);
```